# 老氏讀易得間 Help me understand this, not homework

Tags: grammar, literary-chinese

My question is about the phrase 老氏讀易得間 which I have seen translated as "Laozi's school read between the lines of the I Jing."  I am having trouble getting my reading of it to the point where that makes sense.  Can anyone guide me?  I'm open to that translation being wrong, no investment on my part, just trying to get it right and understand it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

老氏讀易得間

老氏：即老子 Laozi。

讀易：研讀《易經》 to study 《I Jing》，《Book of Changes》

得間： ㄉㄜˊ ㄐㄧㄢˋ , dé jiàn

得：得到 to get, to find, to obtain

間：是「間隙、孔竅」的意思，引申為「竅門、訣竅」。
間 means "the gaps, orifices, openings or holes", and is extended to "the tips, tricks or know-how".

得間：找到訣竅，了解其義。
To discover the tricks and understand the meanings.

老氏讀易得間
When Laozi studied the 《I Jing》, he figured out the knacks.

---

得間 also means 有隙可乘 or 得到機會, to get a chance.

Comment: can you do a wrap-up of the whole phrase at the bottom?

Comment: [讀書得間](http://idiom.wlps.kl.edu.tw/index.php?id=2492)：讀書得了竅門。

Comment: Thank you, your unpacking of the words hits familiar grooves in my brain and seems correct so I accept it.
.

user3306356, and QQi number:534366214 Thank you too!